# Get Angular 2 Form object in typescript class file to set form properties manually

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webforms, angular2-forms

I have a form within a prime ng dialogue control. I don't want to use ngSubmit method in form tag as I have two submit methods depends on some value for this form. I want to manually set this form's submit property on typescript class file. How can I get that form object in ts file to set its "submitted" or "valid" properties manually and take decision based on those? In a word how can I get control of this form in my class file to set or get its internal properties.

**Html:**

```
<p-dialog header="Create New Message" [(visible)]="IsShowNewMessageDialog"
      modal="modal" width="800" height="auto" styleClass="modal-blue" appendTo="body">
<form #f="ngForm" name="newMessageForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <div *ngIf="model && IsShowNewMessageDialog">
        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-11">
                <span style="color:red">{{ErrorMessage}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-2"><label class="">To</label></div>
            <div class="ui-g-10" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error':  f.submitted && !emailTo.valid }">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.emailTo" #emailTo="ngModel"
                       class="text-field"
                       pInputText name="emailTo"
                       placeholder="Email To *" minlength="3"
                       required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-2"><label class="">CC</label></div>
            <div class="ui-g-10">

                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.cC" #CC="ngModel"
                       class="text-field"
                       pInputText name="CC"
                       placeholder="CC" minlength="3">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-2"><label class="">Bcc</label></div>
            <div class="ui-g-10">

                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.bcc" #BCC="ngModel"
                       class="text-field"
                       pInputText name="BCC"
                       placeholder="BCC" minlength="3">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-2"><label class="">Subject</label></div>
            <div class="ui-g-10" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !subject.valid }">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.subject" #subject="ngModel"
                       class="text-field"
                       pInputText name="subject"
                       placeholder="Subject *" minlength="3"
                       required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
                <p-editor name="emailBodyPlain" #emailBodyPlain="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.emailBodyPlain"
                          placeholder="Email Body *" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"
                          minlength="3"></p-editor>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="text-right pr-5">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"
                [disabled]="!f.form.valid"
                (click)="sendNewMail(false)" label="Send">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>&nbsp;Send
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"
                [disabled]="!f.form.valid"
                (click)="saveNewMail(true)" label="Save">
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>&nbsp;Save
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
</p-dialog>
```

**Submit Method:**

```
saveNewMail(isDraft) {
    this.messageCenterService.saveNewMail(this.newMail)
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.IsShowNewMessageDialog = false;
        },
        error => {
            this.ErrorMessage = error.Message;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-submit you can use the (click) event on the submit button and can pass the form values to the component check the following syntax:

```
<button (click)="onSubmit(newMessageForm.value)"></button>
```

you can define onSubmit method in component with a parameter which will contain the form value.
You can also use the following to disable a button based on form validity:

```
<button [disabled]="newMessageForm.invalid"></button>
```

Comment: But how can I set form's property in ts file like this.newMessageForm.IsSubmitted=true? I have called click instead of ngSubmit like on form tag but I want alternative for 
    <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && saveNewMail()" #f="ngForm" novalidate autocomplete="off"> cause here in saveNewMail method, i cant pass static value. for this reason while I submit, textboxes dont show required in read color in the form as I didn't define it in form tag.

Comment: I want f.submitted property set to true in ts file while click is done in respective button.